# Changing a value in an object after it's been requested from server

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm a bit confused over the best practice on how to modify a value in an object after it's been called from a server.

My TS Script:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpService } from "../http.service";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-animals',
  templateUrl: './list-animals.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-animals.component.css'],
  providers: [HttpService]
})
export class ListAgentsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private httpService: HttpService) { }

    items: any[];

  ngOnInit() {
      this.httpService.getData()
          .subscribe(
          data => { this.items = data.resource; },
          error => alert(error),
          () => console.log("Finished")
          );
  }

}
```

My template:

```
<table class="standardTable">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items"><td>{{item.type}}</td><td>{{item.summary}}</td><td>{{item.cost}}</td><td>{{item.available}}</td><td><a [routerLink]="['/animals/edit', item.id]">Now edit an animal</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

If item.type equals "cat", how and where can I modify it to say "feline"?
Do I change it in the service? The actual TS script? Or use a pipe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can Use forEach and change the value of items's type in your service:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.httpService.getData()
      .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.items = data.resource;
        this.items.forEach(element => {
          if(element.type === 'cat'){
          element.type = 'feline';
          }
          return element;
        });
      },
      error => alert(error),
      () => console.log("Finished")
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map()` to alter the array in your service:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.httpService.getData()
      .subscribe(
      data => { 
          this.items = data.resource.map(i => {
              if(i.type === 'cat') i.type = 'feline'
              return i;
          }); 
      },
      error => alert(error),
      () => console.log("Finished")
      );
}
```